# React Hook "useSWR" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

My page receives parameters from the previous page and uses `useSWR` to fetch the data base on the parameters:

```js
export default function Model() {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const selectedMatch = searchParams.get("data")
    if (selectedMatch == "") {
        return <p>no data is found</p>}
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(["api/model", selectedMatch], fetcher)
    return (...)
}
```

It seems that react hooks `useSWR` must be on top of the component before any return and condition, however, I want to handle the empty case of `selectedMatch` before passing to `useSWR`, how can I do it?

Comment: You can create a new component that accepts `selectedMatch` as a property.

Comment: @Titus there is no need for that, 3rd libraries hooks are usually designed to handle such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obstacle here is that `useSWR` is a hook and cannot be called conditionally but [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started) provides, let's say, some tricks with useSWR as [Conditional Fetching](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching)

> Use `null` or pass a function as key to conditionally fetch data. If the function throws or returns a falsy value, SWR will not start the request.

```js
// conditionally fetch
const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(selectedMatch ? ['api/model', selectedMatch] : null, fetcher);
 
// ...or return a falsy value
const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(() => selectedMatch? ["api/model", selectedMatch] : null, fetcher)
```

you can do that and based on the value of `data` you decide what to return

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `null` as the `key` to the `useSWR` hook when you don't want to fetch:

```js
export default function Model() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const selectedMatch = searchParams.get('data');
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(selectedMatch ? ['api/model', 
    selectedMatch] : null, fetcher);

  return (...)
  
}
```